# Using useMediaQuery in material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So after building the complete web application, I've decided to make it mobile friendly. I'm using material ui framework with react. I read the documentation but am not sure as 2 how to use it. So let me give you an overview of what I think how to work it

Say I have this component

```js
function App() {
  const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
    </Button>
  );
}
```

So if I wanna apply styles to button as per the breakpoint(in this case 'sm'), I'd do something like this:

```html
...
<Button styles={{matches? mobileBtn : desktopBtn}}>
...
```

assumming I have defined `mobileBtn` and `desktopBtn`.

Is this the correct approach to use it, or is there some other standard way to do so. Although I don't think there is because if there was it would be included in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, there is a [built-in breakpoints mechanizm](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/) in `makeStyles` so you don't need `useMediaQuery` if you only want to change styles.

For example:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'green',

    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button}>
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-night-4zn76?file=/index.js